# Ansible: ask-pass programmatically

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have a following situation - I need to deploy an app on the ec2 isntance with ansible. The way we have   ec2 setup is that it does not allow ssh'ing as root user. However, when I launch ansible on local machine, I need to run it as root user. Here is snippet of the playbook:

```
  - name: install app
    hosts: ec2
    remote_user: sshUser
    gather_facts: True
    roles: 
       ...
```

Now, it works if I set ask-pass=true and it prompts me to enter the password. However, I was wondering if I could set this programmatic-ally ? I'm guessing I have to do it via setting the inventory with ssh_user, once I'll get the IP. Not sure if it is a right way to do it or if there are better/simpler ways.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I've understood well. If you need to execute commands as root, just add this to your playbook:

```
sudo: true
```

This will execute ansible commands in sudo mode (default user is root, but you can set a different sudo user using the directive: `sudo_user`).